# ngShow doesn't update when pushing to object/array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

It's possible this isn't doable simply but I'm hiding a list if there isn't any data and then was hoping to show this list if something was pushed to it.

Here's a working example - in theory the message 'No todos found' should disappear and then a list appear. I've included a dump of the $scope.todos below the Add button to show the $scope updating.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4hwkwn?p=preview

Can I tell the DOM to update after the add() call?

Comment: your logic isn't quite right `ng-show="todos"` is always going to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show` shows when the value is truthy, in the example you're passing in an empty array. Though the array is empty it is a truthy value, meaning the value coerces to true when evaluated in a boolean context.

If you want to hide the list when it's empty you could do `ng-show="todos.length"` which would evaluate to `0` equalling `false` and thus hiding the element. The same logic applies for `ng-hide`.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vaBeMNThbZMOvnIQycFU?p=preview)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. Sometimes the simplest answers are the hardest. I was looking for a programmatic way to control ng-show and redraw the interface!

Answer (score 0):

Hide or show based on whether the `todos` list is not empty:

```
<p ng-hide="todos.length >0">No todos found.</p>

<ul ng-show="todos.length > 0">
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create expressions for condition to showing or hide items, for example you can write this :

```
<ul ng-show="todos.length >= 1">
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.title}}</li>
    </ul>
```

more informations about expressions : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression